# Basketball Game Monte Carlo Simulation Problem

Tags: python, montecarlo

My code is designed to simulate a basketball game, which simulates a 30-second game with 3 points behind.
The player has to choose whether to shoot a 3-pointer, which requires more time to tie the game and regain possession, or quickly shoot a 2-pointer which is faster, and spend the rest of the time to regain possession by fouling (opponent takes 2 free throws and we regain possession) a player who can't shoot free throws. The game is simulated for about 10000 times to see which play has the highest win rate. The problem is my 'have possession' is a True/False (Boolean), but when I run it through functions, it is returned as an int. Also, the 'pointsdifference' is always the same every time I run the code.

Firstly, why is my Boolean Variable returned as an integer?
And secondly, the win rate should vary since this is a random experiment, but there are only 2 results present. How could this code be adjusted so that my simulation produces random results?

```
import numpy as np

trials=10000
threeptpercentage=34.6
midrangepercentage=49.5
opposingmidrangepercentage=55.4
opponentfreethrowpercentage=60.6
timetoshoot2=4
timetoshoot3=7
timetofoul=2
offensereboundpercent=66.4
ftreboundpercent=64.3
pointsdown=3
timeleft=30
haveposession=True
wins3=0
wins2=0

wintake3=[]
wintake2=[]

def foul(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession):
    #if we don't have the posession, foul to regain posession
    timeleft=timeleft-timetofoul
    #opponent takes 2 free throw
    if np.random.randint(1,101)<=opponentfreethrowpercentage:
        pointsdown=pointsdown+1
    if np.random.randint(1,101)<=opponentfreethrowpercentage:
        pointsdown=pointsdown+1
        haveposession=True
    #opponent misses the freethrow and we rebound it
    else: 
        if np.random.randint(1,101)<=ftreboundpercent:
            haveposession=True
        elif np.random.randint(1,101)<=offensereboundpercent:
            pointsdown=pointsdown+2
            haveposession=True
    return haveposession,timeleft,pointsdown

def take3(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession):
    timeleft = timeleft-timetoshoot3
    #do we make the shot?
    if np.random.randint(1,101)<=threeptpercentage:
        pointsdown=pointsdown-3
        haveposession=False            
        #can we rebound?
    else:
        if np.random.randint(1,101)<=ftreboundpercent:
            haveposession=False
            pointsdown=pointsdown-2
        elif np.random.randint(1,101)<=opposingmidrangepercentage:
            pointsdown=pointsdown+2
            haveposession=True

    return haveposession,timeleft,pointsdown            
#attempt to make a 2 and hope for another posession
def take2(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession):
    #if we are down by 3 or more, take the 2 quickly. if we are down by 2 or less, we tun down the clock
    timeleft = timeleft-timetoshoot2
        #do we make the shot?
    if np.random.randint(1,101)<=midrangepercentage:
        pointsdown=pointsdown-2
        haveposession=False

        #can the opponent rebound?
    else:
        if np.random.randint(1,101)<=ftreboundpercent:
            haveposession=False
            pointsdown=pointsdown-2
    return haveposession,timeleft,pointsdown

for i in range(1,trials+1):     
    while timeleft>0:
        if haveposession==True:
            timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession=take3(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession)
        else:
            timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession=foul(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession)
        if pointsdown<0:
            wintake3.append(wins3)

    while timeleft>0:
        if haveposession==True:
            timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession=take2(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession)
        else:
        timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession=foul(timeleft,pointsdown,haveposession)
    if pointsdown<0:
        wintake2.append(wins2)


winrate3=len(wintake3)*100/trials
winrate2=len(wintake2)*100/trials
print('Winrate if shoot a 3-pointer =',winrate3,'%')
print('Winrate if shoot a 2-pointer =',winrate2,'%')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is for asking *questions* about code.  You have stated what problem you are having, but it is hard to help as "fix this" is entirely subjective as to what you would like to accomplish.  You can restate the question in a more useful way such as "My program is doing this specifically, however I would like it to do this instead. How can I change this code to get the desired result?"

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thank you for your suggestion. I am very new to this so I very appreciate your help ^^

Comment: I can't say I comprehensively understand your program, but the first problem I notice is that in all your functions, the order of the arguments mismatches the order of the returned values (hence you are getting a number when expecting a bool). Also, in your final for loop and 2 inner while loops, the "timeleft" variable is never reset so only the first inner-while loop can execute, and only once as after that point, `timeleft<0` is always true